# Элизия (Copy Elision) в C++

Tags: c++

Задумался насчёт элизии. Вроде и хорошо, оптимизирует программы... Но а что, если конструктор по умолчанию и конструктор копирования должны по-разному инициализировать объекты? Как например в следующем коде.

```
    #include <iostream>

    class A
    {
    private:
        int m_value;
    public:
        A(int value = 0) : m_value {value} { std::cout << "A(int) -> " << m_value << std::endl; }
        A(const A &obj) : m_value {-obj.m_value} { std::cout << "A(const A&) -> " << m_value << std::endl; }
    };

    int main()
    {
        A obj1 { 10 };
        A obj2 { obj1 };
        // obj3.m_value равен 35, а ожидалось -35
        A obj3 { A{35} };

        return 0;
    }
```

Я у себя получил следующий вывод:

*A(int) -> 10* 
*A(const A&) -> -10* 
*A(int) -> 35*

Да, вряд ли кто-то станет так инициализировать объект `obj3`, через анонимный объект, но всё же. Можно ли как-то отключать элизию?

Comment: Может сразу отключить С++?

Comment: Ну, такое поведение вроде как соответствует стандарту, а не является всего лишь необязательной оптимизацией, так что... Хотите копирования? Действуйте явно, как с `obj2`.

Comment: @avp Почему-то я ожидал таких комментариев))

Comment: @AlexF А разве у меня есть побочные эффекты? Только лишь инициализация (ну и std::cout для наглядности)

Comment: @Harry Ну лучше инициализировать явно, да

Comment: "*разве у меня есть побочные эффекты?*" Смотря что считать таковыми... Нарушение семантики копирования точно есть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заковырка возникает из-за предположения, что в `A obj3 { A{35} };` создается анонимный объект. Создание prvalue в С++ теперь вообще никогда само по себе не приводит к созданию объекта. Если необходимо создать именно анонимный объект, то prvalue можно легко метериализовать до вызова конструктора копирования:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class A
{
private:
    int m_value;
public:
    A(int value = 0) : m_value {value} { std::cout << "A(int) -> " << m_value << std::endl; }
    A(const A &obj) : m_value {-obj.m_value} { std::cout << "A(const A&) -> " << m_value << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A obj1 { 10 };
    A obj2 { obj1 };
    // obj3.m_value равен -35
    A obj3 {::std::move(A{35})};

    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aclass+A%0A%7B%0Aprivate:%0A++++int+m_value%3B%0Apublic:%0A++++A(int+value+%3D+0)+:+m_value+%7Bvalue%7D+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22A(int)+-%3E+%22+%3C%3C+m_value+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+%7D%0A++++A(const+A+%26obj)+:+m_value+%7B-obj.m_value%7D+%7B+std::cout+%3C%3C+%22A(const+A%26)+-%3E+%22+%3C%3C+m_value+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++A+obj1+%7B+10+%7D%3B%0A++++A+obj2+%7B+obj1+%7D%3B%0A++++//+obj3.m_value+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD+-35%0A++++A+obj3+%7B::std::move(A%7B35%7D)%7D%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g121,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+12.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: А если у ТС добавится конструктор перемещения со, скажем, обнулением объекта? Тогда же ваш способ не сработает?

Comment: ¿Что значит "не сработает"? Если зачем-то приспичит вызвать именно конструктор копирования вместо перемещения, то это легко сделать `A obj3 {static_cast<A const &>(A{35})};` Если прям очень захочется, то можно написать свои обертки типа `copy_arg` `move_arg` вместо `static_cast`

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли как-то отключать элизию?

У некоторых компиляторов есть флаги для этого. Но поскольку copy elision стала обязательной в C++17, отключив ее, вы будете писать уже не на C++, а на каком-то сомнительном его диалекте.

Поэтому решение только одно - писать нормальные классы, которые не ломаются от убирания лишних копий.